# Converting multiple comma-separated columns into rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, string-splitting

I have an SQL Server database table that holds comma separated values in many columns. For example:

| id | Column B | column c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a,b,c, | 1,2,3, |
| 2 | d, ,f, | 4,5,6, |
| 3 | g,h,i,j, | 7, ,9,8, |

I want to split all the columns into rows and the output should be this:

| id | Column B | column c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | b | 2 |
| 1 | c | 3 |
| 2 | d | 4 |
| 2 |  | 5 |
| 2 | f | 6 |
| 3 | g | 7 |
| 3 | h |  |
| 3 | i | 9 |
| 3 | j | 8 |

I have just given the idea of how to convert these into rows, but my actual columns are more than 30 that need to be separated by comma.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return on your SQL Server?

Comment: @MartinSmith
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31-GDR) (KB5021126) - 14.0.3460.9 (X64)   Jan 25 2023 08:42:43   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: You can use `trim(',' from your_column)` to trim any leading/trailing commas as suggested by Luuk then. Which makes the question the same as the pre-edited one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having comma delimited lists in the database is an anti pattern and having multiple such comma delimited lists that need to be correlated based on order in the list is a huge anti pattern.

This is something that should be represented in a different table.

Hopefully the purpose of this query is to do so. A couple of alternatives....

### OPENJSON

As the ordinal to `STRING_SPLIT` is apparently not available to you - you can use `OPENJSON` as an alternative.

The below will work for SQL Server 2016+ (and you must be on at least that as you do have `STRING_SPLIT` sans ordinal).

You may need to add code to escape characters in `b` and `c` if you find that they contain characters that lead to invalid JSON arrays being constructed.

```
SELECT id,
       ca.b,
       ca.c,
       [key]
FROM   test t
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT b = MAX(CASE WHEN col = 'b' THEN value END),
                           c = MAX(CASE WHEN col = 'c' THEN value END),
                           [key] = cast([key] as int)
                    FROM   (SELECT value,
                                   [key],
                                   'b' AS col
                            FROM   OPENJSON(N'["' + REPLACE(t.b, ',', N'","') + N'"]') AS x
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT value,
                                   [key],
                                   'c' AS col
                            FROM   OPENJSON(N'["' + REPLACE(t.c, ',', N'","') + N'"]') AS x) vals
                            GROUP BY [key]) ca 
ORDER BY id,[key]
```

### Recursive CTE

If you were to have many such columns to deal with you could even consider a [recursive CTE approach](https://stevestedman.com/2012/04/using-a-cte-to-split-a-string-into-rows/). This does add some overhead vs other approaches but it does allow you to do multiple columns per iteration and avoids any need to group or join them by ordinal afterwards.

```
WITH R AS
(
SELECT  id,
        b,
        c,
        bpos0 = 0,
        bpos  = CHARINDEX(',', b), 
        cpos0 = 0,
        cpos  = CHARINDEX(',', c),
        lvl = 1
FROM   test t
UNION ALL
SELECT  id,
        b,
        c,
        bpos0 = R.bpos,
        bpos = CASE WHEN R.bpos > 0 THEN CHARINDEX(',', b, R.bpos + 1) END, 
        cpos0 = R.cpos,
        cpos = CASE WHEN R.cpos > 0 THEN CHARINDEX(',', c, R.cpos + 1) END, 
        lvl = lvl+1
FROM   R
WHERE R.bpos > 0 OR R.cpos > 0 
)
SELECT id, 
       b = SUBSTRING(b, bpos0 + 1, case when bpos = 0 then 80000 else bpos - bpos0 -1 end),
       c = SUBSTRING(c, cpos0 + 1, case when cpos = 0 then 80000 else cpos - cpos0 -1 end)
FROM R
ORDER BY id, lvl
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/IB3YEqFs)

Comment: But: [Does the sequence of the values matter in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16870531/724039), where it says: "It **should** not matter"  

Comment: @Luuk - For a JSON array the `key` is the ordinal in the array. And this is used as the grouping value in the `PIVOT`

Comment: [When OPENJSON parses a JSON array, the function returns the indexes of the elements in the JSON text as keys.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: the recursive CTE is working fine but little bit of scenario changes What if one more comma(,) is added at the end   but the results are given to me the same as previously 

id 
   values( 1 )
   values(  2 )
   values(  3 )

 Column B 
   values( a,b,c , )
   values(  d, ,f,   )
   values( g,h,i,j,  )

 Column B 
   values( 1,2,3,  )
   values(  4,5,6,  )
   values(7, ,9,8,  )

i want the same result as  asked in the question 

rows produced for id 1 are 3,
rows produced for id 2 are 3,
rows produced for id 3 are 4,

How could do that

Comment: i also modify the question , can you please do that with CTE or with solution

Comment: @jawadriaz: Simply adding a WHERE-clause will remove the 'empty' columns that are created because of the additional `,`, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/_tIRomAE   Another way would be removing the extra comma at the end (use: `select trim(',' from 'a,b,c,')`)

Comment: @Luuk the section you are provided in the link it is not working because  it remove that rows if there is empty value occur between comma

Comment: @jawadriaz: oops, I should have used `or` in stead of `and`, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/ItKvDRJg

Comment: @Luuk this is working a little good but not for all empty records

CREATE TABLE test (id INT, b VARCHAR(100), c VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 'a,b,c,', '1,2,3,'),
(2, 'd,,f,', '4,5,6,'),
(3, 'g,h,i,j,', '7,,9,8,'),
(4, 'x,,,,', '5,,,,');
SELECT * FROM test;

not working for id 4
it should create 4 rows for id=4

Comment: @jawadriaz: This is (slowly) diverting from the original question. The original question has been answered, please ask a new question for your new problem.

Comment: You need to decide what the "correct" results are for that example data and make the required changes to the code to fix it. I answered the original question you asked but that doesn't commit me to running a help desk for infinite variations of it

Comment: I've no time to look at it. Next time make sure the question you ask is the one you actually want answered

Comment: @Luuk https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/330742/278674. please look into this

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, b VARCHAR(100), c VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 'a,b,c',    '1,2,3'),
(2, 'd, ,f',    '4,5,6'),
(3, 'g,h,i,j',  '7, ,9,8');
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a,b,c | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | d, ,f | 4,5,6 |
| 3 | g,h,i,j | 7, ,9,8 |

```
SELECT test.id, b.value b, c.value c
FROM test
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(b, ',', 1) b
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(c, ',', 1) c
WHERE b.ordinal = c.ordinal
ORDER BY test.id, b.ordinal;
```

| id | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | b | 2 |
| 1 | c | 3 |
| 2 | d | 4 |
| 2 |  | 5 |
| 2 | f | 6 |
| 3 | g | 7 |
| 3 | h |  |
| 3 | i | 9 |
| 3 | j | 8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/othf0A2w)

---

> ERROR: Procedure or function STRING_SPLIT has too many arguments specified. and also error occur: ordinal is not recognized. In my SQL version, the STRING_SPLIT function accepts only 2 parameters STRING_SPLIT(sentence, ' '); so how to deal with this – jawad riaz

If so then your SQL Server version is not actual. See [@Luuk](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/162995/luuk)'s comment.

```
WITH 
b AS (
  SELECT test.id, b.value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test.id ORDER BY test.id) ordinal
  FROM test
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(b, ',') b  
),
c AS (
  SELECT test.id, c.value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test.id ORDER BY test.id) ordinal
  FROM test
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(c, ',') c
)
SELECT test.id, b.value b, c.value c
FROM test
JOIN b ON test.id = b.id 
JOIN c ON test.id = c.id 
WHERE b.ordinal = c.ordinal
ORDER BY test.id, b.ordinal;
```

| id | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | b | 2 |
| 1 | c | 3 |
| 2 | d | 4 |
| 2 |  | 5 |
| 2 | f | 6 |
| 3 | g | 7 |
| 3 | h |  |
| 3 | i | 9 |
| 3 | j | 8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rwU9NbQA)

But this query is not deterministic.

Comment: About the third parameter to `STRING_SPLIT()`:  "The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only). Beginning with SQL Server 2022 (16.x), the argument and output column are available in SQL Server." (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#:~:text=column%20is%20disabled.-,Note,-The%20enable_ordinal%20argument)

Comment: ERROR: 
Procedure or function STRING_SPLIT has too many arguments specified.
and also error occur: ordinal is not recognized.

In my SQL version, the STRING_SPLIT function accepts only 2  parameters

STRING_SPLIT(sentence, ' ');

so how to deal with this

Comment: @jawadriaz Answer updated.

Comment: @Akina https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/330742/278674

Comment: @jawadriaz Please read and study the meaning for 2nd parameter of STRING_SPLIT function carefully.